# Como fazer para um banner ads aparecer neste caso?

Tags: android, android-studio

O que está faltando ou errado para os banners aparecerem? segui toda documentação, mas tem informações distintas, uma de cada jeito.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".resultados">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-9311879766745441~9248555439"/>


</application>
```

MainActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

XML

```
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
   android:id="@+id/adView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/bbb3"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginTop="157dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
 build.gradle app

 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


          android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tyuu"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
 dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo nada de errado no seu código, apenas algumas linhas desnecessárias mas nada que possa gerar erros.

Vale ressaltar que os anúncios só aparecem na versão RELEASE do app, na versão DEBUG os anúncios não são carregados por padrão!

Tente fazer uma versão RELEASE e ver se vai aparecer algo!